# Angular debugger shows .js files instead of typescript source

Tags: angular

I have very annoying problem since updating from Angular 11 to Angular 14.
In previous version, console debugger shows source in typescript files(example):

[image]

Now it shows everything in js files:

[image]

Is there any solution to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you check if source maps are enabled for both the chrome devtools and your source code settings?

Comment: If your code is effectively generating source maps after compilation you can check if they are enabled in the devtools of your browser by clicking the gear icon for settings > preferences > scroll down until "Sources" > check "Enable JavaScript source maps"